# cast string to int if relevant t-sql

Tags: t-sql, types

I'm using t-sql on microsoft azure.
I have a column called size, the type is nvarchar. It might indicate the size as number (46), as character ('S', 'M', 'L'..) and it also contains nulls.
I want to add a column which will be of numeric data type - it will show me the number for the values that are numbers and null for the rest.

The following query does what I need:

```
select name, size, iif(size like '[0-9][0-9]', cast(size as int), null) as numSize
from product;
```

I was wondering in what other way I can achieve the same. Is there any other function that can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is try_parse() which will convert your string to integer (in this case) otherwise return NULL e.g.

```
select
      name
    , size
    , try_parse(size as int) as numSize
from
    product;
```

On a side note, you tagged this as **tsqlt** which is a (brilliant) unit testing framework for SQL Server.  I have changed it to **tsql**.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the case instruction :

```
select name, size,
 CASE ISNUMERIC(size)
   WHEN 1 THEN CAST(size AS INT)
   ELSE NULL 
 END as numSize
from product
```

Comment: ISNUMERIC is not always trustworthy = try "ISNUMERIC(',')" and the result might surprise you